# Migration from npm to yarn, process is not defined

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, yarn-lock.json

I have recently changed a project that uses `webpack4` that I had on `npm` to `yarn` but after removing the `package-lock.json`, deleting the `node_modules` and installing with `yarn` I now get this on the browser console after compiling with webpack:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
```

I works fine if I go back to `npm`

Comment: Can you share the complete stack trace?

Comment: It's fixed now, I think it was after installing `"react-error-overlay": "6.0.9",` but cannot be sure 100%